# EF Updating entity related table is inserting instead of updating

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an object I am trying to update using Entity Framework 5.

Once I retrieve the existing object and go to update the fields, it correctly updates the base object "coach", but fails to update the Address object and instead inserts it again instead of updating it with a new primary key even though it has been passed the existing primary key to use again.

Any help is appreciated.

Below is a dumbed down version of the code:

```
using (AltairEntities context = new AltairEntities())
                    {
                        dtlCoach coach = context.dtlCoaches.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CoachID == coachId);
                        coach.Name = "Bob";
                        coach.Description = "sample";
                        coach.dtlCoachAddresses.Add(PrepareAddress(coach.dtlCoachAddresses.First().CoachAddressID));
                        context.Database.Connection.Open();
                        context.Entry(coach).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }

public static dtlCoachAddress PrepareAddress(int existingId)
        {
            dtlCoachAddress newAddress = new dtlCoachAddress();
            try
            {
                newAddress.CoachAddressID = existingId;
                newAddress.AddressLine1 = "Line 1";
                newAddress.AddressLine2 = "Line 2";

                return newAddress;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

UPDATE:
So I have found if I feed the existing dtlCoachAddress entity from inside the dtlCoach entity into the PrepareAddress function as a parameter instead of declaring the object as new, it updates correctly.
What is the difference between the dtlCoachAddress object from the entity and the dtlCoachAddress object defined from new, if I pass it all the same parameters? But the two define if the object gets inserted or updated?

Comment: So to simplify your issue, `coach` is getting updated correctly. No issue in that entity.  You also want to add a new `address`. And then reference it back to `coach`. But that's not working. Is that right?

Comment: I want to update the address, not add a new one and keep its reference to coach.

Comment: I would get the address from the address table instead of creating a new object, then assign it to the coach.

Comment: Hi Tarik, this is dumbed down version of the code. In the scenario above your solution sounds easiest, but doesn't help me out in my more complex scenario. What is the difference between the dlCoachAddress of the existing context and the dtlCoachAddress created from new if passed the same Primary Key? @Tarik

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you have arranged PKs and FKs in your entities. So this solution has a few assumptions.

**Updating again to match OPs methods.**

```
using (AltairEntities context = new AltairEntities())
{
    dtlCoach coach = context.dtlCoaches.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CoachID == coachId);
    coach.Name = "Bob";
    coach.Description = "sample";
    //coach.dtlCoachAddresses.Add(PrepareAddress(coach.dtlCoachAddresses.First().CoachAddressID));
    //context.Database.Connection.Open();
    //context.Entry(coach).State = EntityState.Modified;

    var address = context.dtlCoachAddresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CoachAddressID == coachId);       
    if(address != null)
   {
     address.AddressLine1 = "Line 1";
     address.AddressLine2 = "Line 2";                                   
   }     
    context.SaveChanges();
}

/*This function is not required
public static dtlCoachAddress PrepareAddress(int existingId)
{
using (AltairEntities context = new AltairEntities())
{
var address = context.dtlCoachAddresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CoachAddressID == coachId);       
 if(address != null)
 {
     address.AddressLine1 = "Line 1";
     address.AddressLine2 = "Line 2";
     context.SaveChanges();//update an existing address.                             
 }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw ex;
}
}*/
```

Comment: CoachAddressID belongs to the Address object and contains a foreign key of CoachID to link back to the coach object as a 1-N relationship. The dtlCoach table has a constraint to the dtlCoachAddress table so therefor the dtlCoachAddress object is obtainable from the dtlCoach object. @kosala-w

Comment: @Nick Does that mean `address.CoachAddressID == coach.CoachID`. ?

Comment: No, address also contains foreign key called Coach_ID which is used as the constraint to the coach table. This means a 1 coach - multiple address relationship. @kosala-w

Comment: @Nick Ok. Then how do you find which address to be updated only by using `CoachID`. Your results can have multiple addresses if you filter by `CoachID`.

Comment: If you look at the example code I placed, it uses dtlCoachAddress.First() to grab the first Address record from the coach entity...  @kosala-w

Comment: @Nick That's my question; if you have 3 addresses in the database `First()` can be anyone of them. So my question is which one do you expect to be `First()`? To make it bit more clear, if you use `OrderBy(???)`, yes you can have the same result every time. But what field do you use for `OrderBy`?

Comment: It's not so much which one I expect to be first(as that logic is irrelevant currently), but the fact that in the new object created to be returned from the prepare function I assign it the same primary key (CoachAddressID) of the First() found object. I expect this to update the CoachAddress record instead of updating it as it binds the same primary key to an already existing record. @kosala-w

Comment: @Nick Answer updated based on what you said. You dont need to retrieve a coach object at all to update address.

Comment: Wow, please read things before posting...I am not trying to just update the address object, it is part of updating multiple tables. I am trying to update the coach object and the address object. What is the point in opening the entity twice and pulling updating and sending back the two objects in code when I should be able to update both objects at the same time (yes I understand EF does this anyway, but for server code simplicity it is uneccessary).

Comment: @Nick You have to read the comments carefully in my code. My original post was based on the assumptions I made because, you had failed to explain your requirement clearly. Now based on this discussion, it's clear why your code is failing to update the address object. When you write `context.dtlCoachAddresses.Add(address);`, what did you expect EF to do? By the way, have you seen my updated example?

Comment: @Nick This is my last attempt to explain the mistakes in your code. I have pasted your code in my answer and commented out all unwanted parts.

Comment: I will try to explain it so it makes more sense. The object I have shown is a small dummy of an entity object including about 15 related tables. I have added a prepare function for each of these so that my function doesn't end up 200+ lines long. For almost all of these tables, every field except the PK and FK will get updated in the CRUD operation. I don't want to go calling lines like context.dtlCoachAddresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CoachAddressID == coachId)  which makes another db call when Im updating every value except PK and FK, and I already know these values.

Comment: If I write: coach.dtlCoachAddresses.First().AddressLine1 = "bob", it updates dtlCoachAddress correctly, why I can't pass it an entire new dtlCoachAddress object that has the same pk and fk and it updates too, when the object looks identical to the coach.dtlCoachAddresses.First() resulting object. @kosala-w

Comment: @Nick EF does not behave the way that you wanted it to behave and I am not going to explain that here sincemany people have explained it before. You may read the below article to understand why it's inserting a new object even though you have assigned the **existing PK** to your **new object**. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/dn166926.aspx. Unfortunately you will have to change a lot of your codes once you fully understand the issue in your code .